# React Javascript assistant

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, import

I am currently trying to understand React Javascript but facing some problems after installing and enabling a React environment. Before installing node js and enabling the environment using "create-react-app", I typed javascript code in react by using CDN links included in a script tag. This was pretty simple since I was able to go along with it with ease. However, when I installed a react environment, I encountered problems understanding how it works since I don't have to type code in my html file and I also have problems loading it in a web page. Another problem is that I only have to write code in the App.js and index.js files not how I used to with vanilla javascript. When I use live-server, the code I write in my javascript files does not load. How can I understand React better? I'd appreciate to know.

I tried using ReactDOM.render() but I received an error saying render is not a function after I imported a function. I tried to run my code by running "npm start" but the web page did not open whenever I restarted my VS Code. I tried using a live-server but it only loaded code in my html. I thought maybe I should link the javascript files again but it didn't work. So, generally, my problem is with how the files are linked together in React, how they should be exported and imported, what I should do with HTML files and link them with other files, and the importance of the files that are created in the public folder and src folder.

Comment: You cannot use live-server with react. Unlike live-server `npm start` doesn't automatically open a new window, you have to open a browser and input the localhost address  manually - ex: `http://localhost:3000` - beware that your port might be different

Comment: you can find official information here: https://react.dev/learn  and this is an example of an application: https://youtu.be/nrv_O_dIvns?si=nVmep7G6s-TIqy-x